# Input type File With capture="microphone" opening camera on iphone

Tags: javascript, html, audio, record

I have this input `<input type="file" accept="audio/*" capture="microphone">` field 
When i open click on this element on android it open the phone's audio recorder but when i click on same element on iphone it open phone's camera searching from 3 days but found nothing related this.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible on the iPhone at the moment. See the linked duplicate.

Comment: According to https://caniuse.com/#feat=html-media-capture, it looks like this will work for iOS 11, which is good news considering how quickly new iOS versions are adopted.

Comment: I am testing on iOS 11 but it's not working.@DocMax

Comment: It must be more subtle than "supported/unsupported" on iOS 11 then. That's a shame.